# After changing System.Data.OracleClient to Oracle.DataAccess.Client I get error that "Not all variables bound"

Tags: oracle, odp.net

All had worked correctly before I did that.
May be it a common problem? Which associated with ODP namespace changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OracleClient Binds by name by default. ODP.NET binds by position. You will need to set OracleCommand.Bindbyname.

Comment: Is there some way to do this programatically? I have like 100 table adapters and the OracleCommand is only in the designer and that is auto-generated.